# How to define the [float] data type in mysql version (6.0.11-alpha-community)

Tags: mysql, floating-point, floating

When I insert a number as 1234567.1234567 it will translate it to 1234567.1250.
How do I make it to save the correct number?

Comment: that is an alpha edition full of bugs and not teste at all, why do you use it?

Comment: my teammates said use this mysql version (6.0.11-alpha-community). Can you plz suggest me which mysql version is best for work environment.

Comment: alpha version are internal version  for developer to implenet new function and when they public it it is use to test your code against the new functions, but mysql 8 is out for some time now so use this instead

Comment: sure I do and in this version , is it possible to change the float values like this (1234567.1234567) maximum 7.7 values before and after . (dot) if yes suggest me

Comment: no there is no float nor double nor decimal that will do that. here you can test what goes https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e9936423cc7464bbdc0bea7d86b7422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I insert a number as 1234567.1234567 it will translate it to 1234567.1250

[FLOAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html)s are saved in four bytes, allowing for about 2<sup>32</sup> different values.
1234567.1234567 is not one of them.  Encodable values are all some limited integer times a power of 2.

The closest encodable value is 1234567.125 or 9876537*2<sup>-3</sup>.

Code could use `DOUBLE` yet a similar issue applies.
The closest is about  1234567.1234567000065..., may be close enough for OP's purpose.